# Java - String split multiple delimiters from input

Tags: java, split

I'm creating a piglatin translator that accepts multiple words as input multiple times.

Driver:

```
import java.util.*;
public class PigDriver{
public static void main(String[] args){
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
 String t = " ";
 Piglatin p = new Piglatin();
 while(t.length() > 0){
   t = scan.nextLine();
   t = t.toLowerCase();
   p.pigConvert(t);
 }
 p.pigReport();
 }
}
```

My problem is in the pigConvert method

```
   public void pigConvert(String s){
    // store each line
    String lines[] = s.split("[ ,.!?;:]");
    String string1 = lines[0];
    String string2 = lines[1];
    String string3 = lines[2];
   }
```

In order to end the while loop there needs to be an empty input but as soon as I do that I receive this error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
```

which highlights

```
String string2 = lines[1];    //from pigConvert
```

and

```
p.pigReport();    //from Driver
```

I think the issue has something to do with inputting more than one word on each line or how my split is formatted but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: why not print a string representation of "lines" array and see what data it holds prior to performing "String string2 = lines[1]; "?

Comment: Post console input for which you are facing error.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: @jdogg suppose its not a good approach to hard code to get splited array in to strings. think in this scinario `lines[1]` does not exist and you get this exception.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw  when I print the lines array, after using split, using a for loop it prints the input perfectly.

Comment: @j dogg any time if your input string doesn't have any or only one of these delimiter it will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @jdogg specify within your post the exact input you put it and the exact output when you use a for loop and when you get the error.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw  got good hints from the last question I posted. Thanks for your help anyway. I was sending in a String with no value which caused the error

Comment: @jdogg you're welcome! glad to know you've found your problem.